# Update db with ajax and CakePHP

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to ajax update a record in the DB.  Here's my code.  I test out by writing $this->request->data to a log, but it's just blank.  Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8888/cake/tasks/updateStatus",
    data: {id: $(this).attr("id"), status: "checked"}, 
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function(response, status) {
        alert ("Success");
    },
    error: function(response, status) {
        alert('Error! response=' + response + " status=" + status);
    }
});


/* controller */ 

public function updateStatus() {
     $data = json_decode($this->request->data);
     $this->Task->id = $data['id'];
     $this->Task->saveField("status",$data['status']);
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to pass your `id` and `status` into your function and possibly call your function in your controller?

Comment: How would one go about doing that? :)

Comment: Sorry, I am mistaken.  I'll take a look, but I might not have an answer

Comment: Is the problem that the action is not reached or that `$this->request->data` is empty?